# WCF 4 and NetTcpBinding

Tags: c#, wcf, .net-4.0

I am testing out the no configuration features of WCF 4.

I have built a simple service and deployed it to IIS. The service is deployed as a svc file

The client config is empty:

```
<configuration>
    <system.serviceModel>
        <bindings />
        <client />
    </system.serviceModel>
</configuration>
```

The config on the web server is:

```
<system.web>
   <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.0" />  
</system.web>   
<system.serviceModel>
   <behaviors>
      <serviceBehaviors>
         <behavior>
            <serviceMetadata httpGetEnabled="true"/>
            <serviceDebug includeExceptionDetailInFaults="false"/>
         </behavior>
      </serviceBehaviors>
   </behaviors>
   <serviceHostingEnvironment multipleSiteBindingsEnabled="true" /> 
</system.serviceModel> 
<system.webServer>
   <modules runAllManagedModulesForAllRequests="true"/>
</system.webServer>
```

This code works fine:

```
BasicHttpBinding myBinding = new BasicHttpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("http://localhost/Service1.svc");
ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
IService1 wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
int z = wcfClient1.Multiply(composite);
```

This code does not:

```
NetTcpBinding myBinding = new NetTcpBinding();
EndpointAddress myEndpoint = new EndpointAddress("net.tcp://localhost:808/Service1.svc");
ChannelFactory<IService1> myChannelFactory = new ChannelFactory<IService1>(myBinding, myEndpoint);
IService1 wcfClient1 = myChannelFactory.CreateChannel();
int z = wcfClient1.Multiply(composite);
```

The error that I get is:

> Could not connect to
>   net.tcp://localhost/Service1.svc. The
>   connection attempt lasted for a time
>   span of 00:00:02.1041204. TCP error
>   code 10061: No connection could be
>   made because the target machine
>   actively refused it 127.0.0.1:808.

The net.tcp binding is set on the default web site.

I have a feeling that there is something simple that I am missing. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Found the problem. Although net.tcp looked like it was installed for the Default web site it needed to be activated using this command:

```
 appcmd.exe set app "Default Web Site/" /enabledProtocols:http,net.tcp
```

Comment: You can also right click on IIS>Default Website and click Advanced Settings. You will see the last option "Enabled Protocols" and you can add net.tcp there.

Answer (score 6):

I get the feeling that your **Net.Tcp Port Sharing Service** is not enabled.

Comment: Thanks, it was disabled, I enabled and started it. I also did the same for Net Tcp Listener adapter, but I still get the same error

Comment: Is that service is a factor when hosting in IIS?  I didn't think so but I could be wrong.

Comment: @Shiraz, @Brook - Unfortunately I can be of limited help in this matter as I've never hosted a WCF TCP service in IIS. The specifics of your issue just seemed familiar to problems I had hosting one in a regular Windows service.

Comment: Thanks, this fix this problem for me, when the server is not restart correctly (reset), after restart service may  not started automatically.